# Sum of digits in recursion

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, modulo

Super-sum S of an integer x is defined as x if x is single digit number otherwise Super-sum of x is defined as Super-sum of digit-sum of x. Given two numbers n,k  find the Super-sum of the number formed when n is concatenated k times.Note that k is only multiplied with the number when it is at least a 2 digit number

Input:
1987 4

Output:
1

Is there a faster method than this?

```
s,k=input().split()
summ=0
for ele in s:
    summ+=int(ele)
s=summ*int(k)

while s>=10:
    s=str(s)
    summ=0 
    for ele in s:
        summ+=int(ele)
    s=summ
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())
if n<10:
    print(n)
else:
    if ((n*k)%9==0):
        print(9)
    else:
        res=(n*k)%9
```

Any number greater than 9 will have digits repeated that's why you need to take mod of 9 for example 13 will have sum of 1+3 =4 and 13 %9=4 .There will be a special case when mod of 9 will be zero and this will be at number 9,18,27,36 etc which are divisible by 9 and their sum will always be 9 hence return 9 .

Answer (score 0):

The formula used in the accepted answer should actually be proved. So, let's do this.

First, let's prove that for any positive integer number `N`, `N` modulo `9` is the same sum of its digits modulo `9`.

[image]

Having proved the statement above, we easily conclude that `N % 9` provides the needed digit as per challenge description. The only exception is if `N % 9 == 0`, then a digit is `9`.